# Changing data source / series on a RickShaw graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, rickshaw

Using the RickShaw javascript graph library (https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw), I have a number of data series and a list of radio buttons, one for each data series.

```
var graphSeries1 = [
    [{
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 110 }, { x: 2, y: 220 }, { x: 3, y: 330 }, { x: 4, y: 440 }, { x: 5, y: 550 }],
        color: palette.color()
    }],
    [{
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 5 }, { x: 2, y: 7 }, { x: 3, y: 18 }, { x: 4, y: 20 }, { x: 5, y: 30 }],
        color: palette.color()
    }],
    [{
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 105 }, { x: 2, y: 210 }, { x: 3, y: 310 }, { x: 4, y: 405 }, { x: 5, y: 515 }],
        color: palette.color()
    }],
    [{
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 5 }, { x: 2, y: 13 }, { x: 3, y: 12 }, { x: 4, y: 20 }, { x: 5, y: 20 }],
        color: palette.color()
    }],
    [{
        data: [{ x: 1, y: 100 }, { x: 2, y: 200 }, { x: 3, y: 300 }, { x: 4, y: 400 }, { x: 5, y: 500 }],
        color: palette.color()
    }]
];
```

Radio buttons to allow user to change displayed data:

```
<div class="chart_container">
    <div id="y_axisDailtStats"></div>
    <div id="chartDailyStats"></div>
    <form class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input name="DailyStatTimeframe" type="radio" id="DailyStatTimeframe1" value="0" />
            <label for="DailyStatTimeframe1">Previous Day</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input name="DailyStatTimeframe" type="radio" id="DailyStatTimeframe7" value="1" checked />
            <label for="DailyStatTimeframe7">Last 7 Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input name="DailyStatTimeframe" type="radio" id="DailyStatTimeframe30" value="2" />
            <label for="DailyStatTimeframe30">Last 30 Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input name="DailyStatTimeframe" type="radio" id="DailyStatTimeframe91" value="3" />
            <label for="DailyStatTimeframe91">Quarter to date</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4">
            <input name="DailyStatTimeframe" type="radio" id="DailyStatTimeframe365" value="4" />
            <label for="DailyStatTimeframe365">Year to day</label>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I am displaying the initial set of data on a graph and trying to update the graph to display and an alternate data series when the corresponding radio button is selected.

I have the solution working, but it seems clunky and manual.  I'm sure I'm missing a more elegant / official way of changing the displayed data series.

```
$("input[name=DailyStatTimeframe]").change(function (e) {
    // Remove existing graph from DOM...
    var myNode = document.getElementById("chartDailyStats");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }

    // Create new graph object...
    graph1 = new Rickshaw.Graph({
        element: document.querySelector("#chartDailyStats"),
        renderer: 'bar',
        height: 360,
        unstack: true,
        series: graphSeries1[e.target.value]
    });
    graph1.render();
});
```

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/techwareone/ftwcjjbo/

Answer (score 2):

You could just update the object you bound to the series. You have to change your code a bit, like so

```
var data = [];
data.push(graphSeries1[1][0]);
var graph1 = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    element: document.querySelector("#chartDailyStats"),
    renderer: 'bar',
    height: 360,
    unstack: true,
    series: data
});
...
```

and

```
$("input[name=DailyStatTimeframe]").change(function (e) {
    data[0] = graphSeries1[e.target.value][0];
    graph1.update();
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/96L9p5kp/

Comment: That works, and is a clear improvement over my solution. I still wonder though if there is a better way, provided within the Rickshaw library that I'm missing...

Comment: There is also an option to toggle series on and off to btw.

Comment: Having thought about it a little more, toggling on/off is probably the intended way of handling this requirement.  If you'd like to update your answer with this as a secondary suggestion then I'll happily mark it as accepted.